# On iOS, how do we draw things on screen in viewDidLoad when some dimension info is not available?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

At the app start up, I am directly drawing things on a `CGBitmapContext`, converting it to `CGImage`, and then set it to the view's layer in `viewDidAppear`.

It is actually quite fast, but since Apple requires adding a Launch image to the app, I added a static image of what the screen would look like as the Launch image.

However, what happens next is that when the app starts up, the Launch image shows up, but the screen will blank out after 0.5 to 1 second, I think due to `viewDidLoad` kick in and `viewDidAppear` starts to run, but at its beginning, the screen is all blank.

Then after 0.5 second, everything shows up, but this creates a "flash" of white screen.

So looks like there are two options at least, which are

1. just make the Launch image totally blank, but I am not sure whether Apple will reject the app because they'd like a "static image of what the app initially looks like"... but I wonder if the initial image shows up so quickly (0.5 to 1 second, will they still mind?)
2. the other option is to move all the drawing from `viewDidAppear` to `viewDidLoad`, but I found that some info are missing in `viewDidLoad`, such as `self.view.bounds` in `viewDidLoad` is `{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}}`, and it changes to the correct `{{0, 0}, {320, 460}}` in `viewDidAppear` (it is being tested on an iPhone 4S).

So I think some view info is not yet set correctly in `viewDidLoad`, and it is a dilemma.  One way is maybe to check whether it is iPad or iPhone, and hardcode the `self.view.bounds` value, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Create your CGImage on a background thread which you kick off during viewWillAppear, you'll have the dimensions then.

Perhaps set a view background in viewDidLoad to be the same as your launch image, so that while you're drawing your CGImage, the user does not see the flicker.

Comment: why not move all the code from `viewDidAppear` to `viewWillAppear` then? (instead of moving to `viewDidLoad`)  I just tried printing out `self.view.bounds` and it is already set correctly.  (by the way is there additional advantage of drawing the CGImage in the thread versus right inside of `viewWillAppear`?)

Comment: Exactly what I do - use a launch image, make the same image (status bar width smaller) and use as the backing view of the first view controller, then when I have the view I want to show animate the new view in, the backing view out, then in a completion block release the backing view image.

Comment: @DavidH I thought Apple's intention (one possible way, but probably the main way they want) is that we show a static image, "as if" the app already properly rendered it, so the user can feel it is fast and loading things up already, according to the HIG, and Apple doesn't want people to use a "Splash" screen or credit screen.  And when the real things are being drawn, I think the intention is that it silently comes in, and if there is fade out of the static image and fade in the real thing, it may be "heavy" according to what HIG wanted us to do

Comment: I'm giving you a technique to not get flashing, not instructing you on what to show. In my app there can be a login view (for new people), or a view with a list of products (which I get from the web). So no way to get a single launch image. What I do for login (which is similar to what you want to do) is to have a launch image of a dark piece of wood, then when I launch I use the same imagee but cropped up top for the status bar as a background, and then finally when the login view gets viewDidAppear I animate in my other content that "floats" on top of the backdrop. No flashing.

Comment: I ran out of comment space. So, yes, if you want to follow the HIG (which it seems few if anyone does, and even Apple seems to ignore now, that was written for early apps when launch took forever) - then you would try to make your launch image exactly like your first view.

Comment: interesting... I realize that for games, typically they don't show a static screen of start screen (such as the screen to choose a level), but will in fact show a splash screen.  Also, for some games like Plants vs Zombies, the start up loading time is like 10 seconds, and it'd be pretty confusing if it shows a "static screen of what will come up next" and it is static for 10 seconds.  A "loading" progress bar is more appropriate